# Execute HTTP/S stream on Windows

Tags: windows, http, https, application-launch

How to execute HTTPS download link to an exe file directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly run a file from the web, but you can download the file first, then run it. This PowerShell one-liner ought to do it:

```
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("tmpfile.exe", (Invoke-WebRequest "https://example.com/app.exe").Content); Start-Process tmpfile.exe
```

That will leave behind a `tmpfile.exe` program in the current directory. To instead leave it in the Temp directory (where it will hopefully be cleaned up soon):

```
$tmpPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + ".exe"; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tmpPath, (Invoke-WebRequest "https://example.com/app.exe").Content); Start-Process $tmpPath
```

Using these, you could probably rig up a script to download and run an EXE from an arbitrary URL. You can invoke a PowerShell command from a normal command prompt or batch file by putting `powershell -command` before it:

```
@echo off
rem Downloads and runs an EXE from a URL.
powershell -command $tmpPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName() + '.exe'; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($tmpPath, (Invoke-WebRequest "%*").Content); Start-Process $tmpPath
```